# Change the Drawable position inside the button

Tags: android, button

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32px"
    android:layout_marginTop="32px"
    android:layout_marginRight="32px"
    android:background="#44C4C5"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_ON"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="ON"
    android:textFontWeight="300"
    android:textSize="32px"></Button>
```

If the Button is off, android drawable should change to android:drawableLeft= "@drawable/ic_Off" and text is OFF.
If the Button is On, android drawable should change to android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_ON" and text is ON.

Comment: if you want like this then don't take button instead create layout and conditionally on or off it.

Comment: why not a Switch?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout for this, where there is an `ImageView` to the left and right hand side of a `TextView`. You can then set the visibility of the left/ right `ImageView`s programmatically based on whether the button is in the ON or OFF state.

on_off_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#44C4C5">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/offImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_OFF"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/onOffTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ON"
        android:textFontWeight="300"
        android:textSize="32sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/onImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ON"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In your layout file where you want the button to be:

```
    ...
    
    <include
        android:id="@+id/onOffButton"
        layout="@layout/on_off_button"/>

    ...
```

In your activity or fragment then you will need to get a reference to the button with `findViewById<View>(R.id.onOffButton)` and set up an on click listener to set the visibility of the `offImageView` or `onImageView` based on the state.